# why my site is not crawled by google (my site is in a directory of root folder)

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-crawlers, google-search-console

I have 2 WordPress in my host. My main WordPress in root folder and work correctly and index by google. I have a directory in root folder and second WordPress is in this folder and works fine.
i have a serious problem,  my second WordPress not indexed by google . I submit request indexing from google search console but not working . i have robbot.txt and sitemap.xml for two sites and every thing is correct but still this problem not solved.
it is a Forum and very important for me to index by google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Search Engine Visibility:Discourage search engines from indexing this site

is disabled on your Reading Settings -> Can check through Setting -> Reading

Comment: it is unchecked this part